Text decoration span over <span>s
I have a <ul> element, with list items as such:
<ul>
    <li class="list__item">
        <span class="list__quantity">3</span>
        <span class="list__unit">Kg</span>
        <span class="list__name">Tomatos</span>
     </li>
     <li class="list__item">
        <span class="list__quantity">3</span>
        <span class="list__unit">Kg</span>
        <span class="list__name">Cucmbers</span>
      </li>
</ul>

I want to have a text-decoration: line-through that spans across an entire list item. I've tried:

.list__item {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

But my list looks like this:

I want the line to be continuous, spanning the whole list item.
Is that possible?

You could use ::before pseudo element for this. Only drawback is you will have to limit the width of li elements to max-content or you can set the values manually for width of the line.
Alternatively you can use the psuedo element on the span itself. That will require some hit and trial to get the exact width and position as per your entire list-data. First method is a bit easier and minimalist but you can go for second one if you need the li to be width:100%


.list__item {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: max-content;
}

.list__item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}
<ul>
  <li class="list__item">
    <span class="list__quantity">3</span>
    <span class="list__unit">Kg</span>
    <span class="list__name">Tomatos</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <span class="list__quantity">3</span>
    <span class="list__unit">Kg</span>
    <span class="list__name">Cucmbers</span>
  </li>
</ul>




It sucks that there's no more straight-forward way to do this, but whatever :)

Don't use line-through, use a pseudo-element positioned over the spans


.list__item {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /*     text-decoration: line-through; */
  position: relative;
  width: min-content;
}

.list__item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}

span {
  padding: 0 0.25em;
}
<ul>
  <li class="list__item">
    <span class="list__quantity">3</span>
    <span class="list__unit">Kg</span>
    <span class="list__name">Tomatos</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <span class="list__quantity">3</span>
    <span class="list__unit">Kg</span>
    <span class="list__name">Cucmbers</span>
  </li>
</ul>



removed image
